# NSIS Modern UI Finish Page

Tags: nsis

I would like to build an installer for my application using NSIS, but I faced a problem on the finish page. It looks like a big white rectangle around a checkbox. The rectangle cuts the '***Nullsoft Install System v3.03***' subtitle. Here it is a screenshot:

[image]

Here it is a code:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

Name "My cool app"
OutFile "MyCoolAppInstaller.exe"

InstallDir "C:\MyCoolApp"

!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\app.exe"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_TEXT "Run App now"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_NOTCHECKED
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

Section
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  File app.exe
  File smth.res
SectionEnd
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add at least one language after the page macros:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\app.exe"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_TEXT "Run App now"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_NOTCHECKED
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```

Adding a language will finalize some of the things in the UI and it does not look correct without it.

Comment: Wow! I couldn't imagine, that it would look so beautiful (: But IMO decision (and behaviour) is not obvious! But maybe I didn't read the documentation carefully

Comment: The compiler should print plenty of warnings if you forget the language macro.